# Bash script to make passwordless connection

Tags: shell-script, ssh, password, authentication, passwd

I want to make passwordless connection with help of bash scripting. The requirement is that user has to just provide password.

Point to be considered:

- 1) There is no generated public/private key in the server (if using `ssh-keygen` in shell, then all requested prompts must be answered via script)
- 2) `ssh-copy-id` command can ask password for making passwordless connection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command   There are a lot of answers there but I like the fifth answer personally.

Comment: @Jetchisel I can sort answers by "active", "oldest", and "votes". Sole deletion of one answer may change all these sortings. "Fifth answer" is ill-defined.

Comment: Ok, then the expect utility is the answer, just read the whole link. Otherwise this another duplicate of what is being asked in that link.